# What do the wings and features in the description of the heavenly creature in Ezekiel Chapter 1 signify?

Tags: ezekiel, metaphor

I believe the faces of the creature may represent the different parts of God's creation as holiness illustrated. Soul of Man, Heart of a Lion, Strength of an Ox, Mind of an Eagle. I'm curious what the wings and wheels may signify?

> 10As for the form of their faces, each had the face of a man; all four had the face of a lion on the right and the face of a bull on the left, and all four had the face of an eagle. 11Such were their faces. Their wings were spread out above; each had two touching another being, and two covering their bodies. Ezekiel 1:10-11

Allegorically mean sovereignty perhaps? Assuming the eyes mean 'discernment'.

> Moses was a hundred and twenty years old when he died, yet his eyes were not weak nor his strength gone. Deuteronomy 34:7
>
> Do not revile the king even in your thoughts, or curse the rich in your bedroom, because a bird in the sky may carry your words, and a bird on the wing may report what you say. Ecclesiastes 10:20

Answer (score 1):

There has been a lot of speculation about the meaning of the four faces, going back to earlier Jewish commentary: see the widely-cited comment from [Exodus Rabbah 23:13](http://www.sefaria.org/Shemot_Rabbah.23.13?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) (exegetical compilation, *circa* 750-900 c.e.) -

> Four kinds of proud beings were created in the world: the proudest of all—man; of birds—the eagle; of domestic animals—the ox; of wild animals—the lion; and all of them are stationed beneath the chariot of the Holy One....

Cited from M. Greenberg, *[Ezekiel 1-20](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5rTYAAAAMAAJ)* (Anchor Bible; Doubleday, 1983), p. 56.

Daniel Block explains the four faces as being "perfectly natural for Ezekiel's world", and illustrates this way:

- lion = "strength, ferocity, courage" (cf. Jdg 14:18; 2 Sam 1:12; 17:10);
- eagle = "swiftest and most stately of birds" (cf. Deut 28:49; Isa 40:31; Jer 48:40);
- ox = "most valuable domestic animal ... symbol of fertility and divinity" (cf. Ps 106:19-20);
- human = "created as the image of God and invested with divine majesty" (cf. Gen 1:28; Psalm 8).

*from* D.I. Block, *[Ezekiel 1-24](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0GF0EUpEAkEC&printsec=frontcover)* (Eerdmans 1997), p. 96.

Leslie Allen, *[Ezekiel 1-19](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0849908302)* (Word, 1994), p. 29, includes a line-drawing of this 18th C. bce "Assyrian representation of a god with four human faces" (now in the [Oriental Institute in Chicago](https://oi.uchicago.edu/collections/highlights/highlights-collection-mesopotamia)):

[image: 8th C. Assyrian art]

The concept, then, appears not to be unique to Ezekiel, but the assemblage of *these* four faces is distinctive to Ezekiel, and contributes to the impressionistic quality ("form" of their "appearance", 1:5) of the vision.

Answer (score 0):

> *I'm curious what the wings and wheels may signify ?*

*Wings* signify birds, which fly up to heaven, where the stars reside, whose (apparent) motion 
 around the earth follows circular patterns, reminiscent of a *wheel*. Notice that apart from their 
 obvious zoological interpretation, the *ox* and the *lion* also possess an astronomical one — and 
 the Babylonians, in whose time Ezekiel prophesied, were also master astronomers. The number 
 *four*, mentioned almost fifty times in the book, also lends itself to a similar symbolism, representing 
 the four winds or cardinal directions. The (countless) night stars have been regarded by various 
 ancient or primitive civilizations as being the *eyes* of God, according to [Eliade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mircea_Eliade). Indeed, the Jews 
 were probably familiar from their previous captivity with Egyptian myths concerning the Sun and 
 the Moon, believed to be the two *eyes* of [Horus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horus), who injured one of them in a battle with [Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(deity)), thus 
 causing the lessening of the moon's radiance. I hope all of this will help shed some further light 
 (no pun intended) into Ezekiel's celestial imagery.